# File path not correct for Path object in java

Tags: java

I have a program which monitors any changes in the directory.

This is the output of the program.

```
C:\REST API\source\data_id.txt

The new file :data_id.txtEvent :ENTRY_CREATE

C:\REST API\source\New folder    

The new file :New folderEvent :ENTRY_CREATE

C:\REST API\source\NhuPhutBanDau-NooPhuocThinh-4549467.doc

The new file :NhuPhutBanDau-NooPhuocThinh-4549467.docEvent :ENTRY_CREATE
```

My program monitors the root directory `C:/REST API/source` for any changes. When I copy `data_id.txt` file into the root directory, it's able to detect new file as shown in the output above and the directory as well.

After this, when I try to create a folder, it's also able to detect that there's a new folder and shows the new folder directory in the output.

But the problem is that when I try to put a file into the newly created folder, it's again able to detect changes in the new folder  `C:\REST API\source\New folder` which is not the root directory set in my program which is `C:\REST API\source`.

I need the program to detect changes only in the root directory.

Can someone guide me on this?

This is my source code:

```
public class fileStatus {

    private final WatchService svc = null;
    private final HashMap<WatchKey , Path> keyMap = null;

    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, JSONException, InterruptedException
    {
     try(WatchService svc = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) 
        {
            Map<WatchKey, Path> keyMap = new HashMap<>();
            Path path = Paths.get("C:/REST API/source/");
            fileStatus fs = new fileStatus();
            fs.registerAll(path,keyMap,svc);
            WatchKey wk ;
           do 
           {

                wk = svc.take();
                Path dir = keyMap.get(wk);
                for(WatchEvent<?> event : wk.pollEvents())
                {
                    WatchEvent.Kind<?> type = event.kind();
                    Path fileName = (Path)event.context();
                    Path child = path.resolve(fileName);
                    System.out.println(child);
                    if (Files.isDirectory(child, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS))
                    {
                        if(type == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE)
                        {
                            registerAll(child,keyMap,svc);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("\nThe new file :"+fileName+ "Event :" +type);  
                }
           }while(wk.reset());
        }
     catch(IOException e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

    }

    private static void registerAll(Path path, Map<WatchKey, Path> keyMap, WatchService svc) throws IOException 
    {
        Files.walkFileTree(path,new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>()
                {
                   public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException
                   {
                       if(attrs.isDirectory())
                       {
                           keyMap.put(path.register(svc, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE),path);
                       }
                       return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                   }
                });

    }

}
```

Comment: The *Java compiler* is certainly not showing that output. *Your program* is.

Comment: Ask yourself this question: What is the purpose of `keyMap`?

Comment: use to register the watcher service and event

Comment: Used to get the *directory* of the events, aka variable `dir`. Perhaps you should change `Path child = path.resolve(fileName)` to `Path child = dir.resolve(fileName)`, so you don't resolve them all against the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of places where you are registering the path for monitoring file creation which is not necessary.

1. You can remove this entire block from your `main` method

   ```
               if (Files.isDirectory(child, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                   if (type == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE) {
                       registerAll(child, keyMap, svc);
                   }
               }
   ```
2. You should not do a walk tree in the `registerAll` method. So instead of this,

   ```
   Files.walkFileTree(path,new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>()
   {
      public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException
      {
          if(attrs.isDirectory())
          {
              keyMap.put(path.register(svc, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE),path);
          }
          return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
      }
   });
   ```

Just use this:

```
keyMap.put(path.register(svc, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE),path);
```

The above snippets of code are adding the inner folders of your root directory recursively to the keymap. That's why you are seeing the unexpected behavior.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i tested your method before, when i try to create a new folder,it's able to detect but when i try to put the file into the new created folder, it's not able to detect the new file, so i develop my program become like that according the stuff i found online

Comment: But did you not say that you should be able to monitor only the *root* directory and not the sub folders?